# Como resolver este problema no DataTables?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Estou com um problema no DataTables que está me tirando o sono. Tenho o seguinte código. Ele até aparece o  datatable mas as funções da tabela não funcionam. O next não aparece nem o prev. Se eu retirar o destroy ele volta na mensagem: Warning: Cannot reinitialise DataTable. O que poder ser?

```
 function retorna_cliente()
 {
 //  $('.mostra_clientes .table').DataTable().destroy();
   var oTable = $('.mostra_clientes .table').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 4,
  "ajax": {
    "url": url_base + "clientes",
    "type": "GET",
    "dataSrc": "",
  },
  "columns": [
    {
      "data": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+data['id']+"' name='verifica_check_box[]' id='verifica_check_box' class='flat'/>";
      }
    },
    { "data":"nome"},
    { "data":"data_nascimento"},
    { "data":"telefone"},
    { "data":"celular"},
    { "data":"cpf"},
    { "data":"endereco"},
    { "data":"email"},

  ], language: {
    "sProcessing":   "Carregando...",
    "sLengthMenu":   "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords":  "Não foram encontrados resultados",
    "sInfo":         "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty":    "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",
    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
    "sSearch":       "Buscar:",
    "sUrl":          "",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sFirst":    "Primeiro",
      "sPrevious": "Anterior",
      "sNext":     "Seguinte",
      "sLast":     "Último"
    }
  },
  //"bDestroy": true,
});

oTable.ajax.reload(null, false);

oTable.destroy();
```

}

Comment: Sugiro criar dois métodos, um para montar a tabela com o .DataTable e outro somente para recarregar os dados com ajax.reload. Quando o comando .DataTable é chamado numa tabela já existente, acontece esse erro. Minha tabela não era ajax, então o que eu fazia era remover ela completamente e montar do zero chamando o .DataTable de novo.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme especificado na [documentação oficial](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3), esse erro ocorre quando tentamos reiniciar uma tabela já iniciada. Por padrão, o DataTables não nos deixa alterar uma tabela que já foi criada, mas existe a configuração **destroy**, que pode ser passada como `true` ao iniciar a tabela, dessa forma:

```
$('#exemplo').DataTable({
  destroy: true,
  paging:false
});
```

Essa configuração faz com que a tabela atual seja destruída antes de ser criada uma nova.